# Refactoring the swift code

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on swift project.After 1 month I need to refactor the code as we have done in objective c. I need to change some class names, properties and method names. But problem is that when I go to refactor the code but  It showing me an error.
Error is "Xcode can only refactor C and Objective-C code."

Is there any way to refactor the code because there are 50+files to change the code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. We're stuck with "Find>Find & Replace in Project".